# Sum from Max Value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I try to get sum of max value from a table :

```
select 
  a.sp_capex_01_master_key,
  a.sp_capex_01_master_wbs_id,
  format((
  (
    select
      sum(maxVal)
    from 
      (
        select max(w.sp_capex_01_trans_realisasi) as maxVal 
        from sp_capex_01.sp_capex_01_trans w 
        where w.sp_capex_01_master_wbs_id='P2-14101-01' 
        group by w.sp_capex_01_master_key 
      ) t
  ) / b.sp_capex_01_master_wbs_bud * 100
  ),2) as 'PerBudget'
from sp_capex_01_master a
join sp_capex_01.sp_capex_01_master_wbs b 
  on a.sp_capex_01_master_wbs_id=b.sp_capex_01_master_wbs_id;
```

if I set value to `w.sp_capex_01_master_wbs_id='P2-14101-01'`, then I get the result with wrong value.

But when I change this to  `w.sp_capex_01_master_wbs_id=a.sp_capex_01_master_wbs_id`, then I get following error message :

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'a.sp_capex_01_master_wbs_id' in 'where clause'    0.000 sec
```

How can I get Sum of the Max Value?

Comment: A correlated subquery can refer to tables from the outer query, but it only goes one level. You can't refer to the outer table in a doubly-nested subquery.

Comment: Thank you for your information, there's no other way to get the result?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow! There *may be* other ways to achieve your requirements, but we need to look at some sample data. Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 0):

Join with a subquery that groups by the column you want to match.

```
SELECT 
  a.sp_capex_01_master_key,
  a.sp_capex_01_master_wbs_id,
  FORMAT(sum_maxval / b.sp_capex_01_master_wbs_bud * 100, 2) AS PerBudget
FROM sp_capex_01_master a
JOIN sp_capex_01.sp_capex_01_master_wbs b ON a.sp_capex_01_master_wbs_id=b.sp_capex_01_master_wbs_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT sp_capex_01_master_wbs_id, SUM(maxVal) AS sum_maxval
    FROM (
        select w.sp_capex_01_master_wbs_id, max(w.sp_capex_01_trans_realisasi) as maxVal 
        from sp_capex_01.sp_capex_01_trans w 
        group by w.sp_capex_01_master_wbs_id, w.sp_capex_01_master_key
    ) AS w1
    GROUP BY sp_capex_01_master_wbs_id
) AS w2 ON w2.sp_capex_01_master_wbs_id = a.sp_capex_01_master_wbs_id
```

Comment: Wow, Thank a lot Mr. Barmar, now I can get the result :-)